# @joincolunm com foreignKey hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotation

Olá eu queria fazer uma chave estrangeira, porém não estou entendendo a sintaxe.

Na classe Endereco:

```
@Embeddable
@Table(name = "tab_endereco")
public class Endereco {

@Column(length = 40, nullable = false)
private String logradouro;

@Column(length = 40, nullable = false)
private String bairro;

@JoinColumn(columnDefinition = "char(3)", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="fk_cidade"))
private Cidade cidade;
```

Na classe Cidade, onde que pegar a sigla:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tab_cidade")
public class Cidade {


@Id
@JoinColumn(columnDefinition = "char(3)", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "fk_cidade")
private String sigla;

@Column(length = 40, nullable = false)
private String nome;

@Column(columnDefinition = "char(2)", nullable = false)
private Estado estado;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, segue um exemplo de como vc pode criar relacionamento em suas classes.

Classe estado:

```
@Entity
public class Estado {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String nome;
private String sigla;
```

Quanto a Classe Cidade, nesta classe tomei a liberdade de colocar como chave primária um campo de Id, não sei se entenderia a sua necessidade, porém vc pode mudar conforme regras do seu projeto:

```
@Entity
public class Cidade {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long cidadeId;
private String nome;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "estadoId")
private Estado estado;
```

Por fim a classe endereço, nesta classe não coloquei o campo estado pois a Cidade já possui um estado vinculado a ela:

```
public class Endereço {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String logradouro;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cidadeId")
private Cidade cidade;
```

Então vamos lá:

`@Id` = Indica qual é o atributo de identificação única do objeto a ser persistido;

`@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` = Ao usar esta anotação o SGDB fica responsável por gerar o valor do ID do objeto de maneira incremental;

`@ManyToOne` = Define uma relação de cardinalidade de muitos para um, ou seja Muitos endereços estão em uma única cidade por exemplo;

No seu código percebi que vc tinha utilizado uma anotação `@Embeddable`, no meu exemplo retirei pois esta anotação se utiliza quando trabalha-se com chave composta.

Valeu.

Comment: Na classe `Cidade`, o atributo `estado` não deveria ser `@ManyToOne`? em vez de `@OneToMany`?

Comment: Vc esta certo, fiz a correção.

Comment: Nesse caso, o @ManyToOne está dizendo que o muitos Endereço para uma Cidade? E como o private Cidade cidade identifica qual o atributo da classe Cidade é o que vai servir de chave estrangeira? Através do @Id?

Comment: E o @JoinColumn(name = "cidadeId"), o name dentro da JoinColunm tem que ser o mesmo nome do atributo(private Long cidadeId) ?

Comment: Olá Danilo, sim, quando vc faz o mapeamento para definir o relacionamento entre as entidades a própria API já faz o o relacionamento para a chave primária da classe que estamos vinculando, Quanto a utilizar o mesmo nome, não é necessário, eu utilizo para manter mais fácil a leitura.

Comment: Danilo, tem um material que é um resumo de algumas anotações que facilita o entendimento da utilização: http://www.techferry.com/articles/hibernate-jpa-annotations.html